# How to use node--[content type]--teaser.html.twig in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have created a custom content type named Question and have a few simple fields in addition to one reference entity created by Paragraph module.
I have seen some documentation about template suggestion, but I did not understand how to use them.
How I can use a custom template to show all of my questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added fields to an entity through the administrative interface (i.e. Manage Fields), then you should not need to create a custom twig template for a generic display of your fields.

What you are looking for is the Manage Display tab of your custom Entity.  You can configure each field to display in different ways through the UI.  This includes reference fields.

You can also configure the display of your Entity in accordance with different display types, including a teaser.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/administering-drupal-8-site/managing-content-0/specify-how-fields-are-displayed

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your answer @jhchnc
I know that I am trying to implement something different like a contest, I need to show a question with the answers and provide a button to switch to the next answer and in the end to calculate how many right answers the user made.

So I need a way to display the data in the template the question and the answers with checkboxes!

Comment: I understand that you have a Question entity type.  How are your answers related to that entity?  Are they fields?  Is that the reference Entity?

Comment: reference entity @jhchnc

Answer (score 0):

You can copy node.html.twig from your base theme (Classy) and copy to your active theme template folder and rename to node--[content-type-mechine-name]--teaser.html.twig.

If you use  {{ content }} it should output the content the way you set up in the managed display (admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/display). This is the default behaviour.

If you want more control and display filed by field, you can do something like this.

```html
<div class="left">
  {{ content.field_abc }}
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  {{ content.field_xyz }}
 </div>
```